# Grant privileges on database to a user

Tags: oracle, sql-grant

I want to grant select privilege to a particular user in Oracle. Its possible in mysql with following query

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, DELETE ON database TO username@'localhost' IDENTIFIED      
BY 'password';
```

Is there any way we can achieve this in Oracle ?

Comment: -1 for no research effort : |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What MySQL calls a "database" is more similar to what Oracle calls a "schema".  Oracle does not have the ability to grant privileges on all objects in a schema to a particular user, you have to grant the privileges on each object individually.  You can use a bit of dynamic SQL to simplify the initial grant

```
BEGIN
  FOR x IN (SELECT *
              FROM dba_tables
             WHERE owner = <<name of schema>>)
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT select, insert, delete ON ' || 
                         x.owner || '.' || x.table_name ||
                         ' TO <<username>>';
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Every time you create a new object in the schema, though, you'll need to either grant the same privileges on the new object to the user or you'll need to re-run the PL/SQL block above.  If you really want to, a DDL trigger could submit a job that would grant the privileges automatically when new objects are created but that is not particularly recommended.

From a managability perspective, you would generally create a role that would be assigned all these privileges and then [assign that role to whatever set of users actually need those DML privileges](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e16543/authorization.htm).  That allows you to easily assign the same role to everyone in the organization that needs the same set of privileges rather than managing privileges on `n` objects for `m` users.

Comment: You might want to look at [using roles](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e16543/authorization.htm) to manage privileges, and then granting the appropriate role to the user, to simplify future changes. (That's aimed at @chetan, not Justin, obviously!)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is with a GRANT statement :
[GRANT in Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9013.htm#SQLRF01603)

You must first create a user with [CREATE USER](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_8003.htm#i2065278).

Comment: You don't *have* to have a separate `create user` statement; if you `grant` with the `identified by` clause then the user will be created if it doesn't already exist. That's [mentioned in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9013.htm#sthref8966) you linked to. But you can't do a global grant for all objects in a schema, as Justin pointed out; closest is perhaps granting a role which has all the required privileges.